# Syncing nav buttons with content (CSS3)

Tags: css

Imagine the following text...

```
<h2 id="intro">Introduction</h2>
<p>Hello World</p>

<h2 id="summary">Summary</h2>
<p>Summary</p>
```

And imagine a sidebar that links to the headings...

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#intro">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#summary">Summary</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Does anyone know how to sync the content with the nav links so that the first link is highlighted when a user scrolls down to Introduction, and the second link is highlighted when you scroll down farther to Summary?

You can see an example @ http://html5up.net/prologue

I've been playing with the code but couldn't figure out how it's done. Also, I've tentatively adopted Bootstrap, while this the above link is a different program.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to use javascript(jquery) this is not fully supported by css3 only now mybe in the future.

```js
$('nav a[href*=#]').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var scrollTo = $(id).offset().top;
     
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("active").siblings("li").removeClass("active");
    
    $('html,body').animate({
        'scrollTop': scrollTo
    }, 300);
});
window.addEventListener("scroll",highlighting, false);

function highlighting() {
    var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(currentPosition);
    $('nav a[href*=#]').removeClass('active');
    $('h2').each(function () {
        var headerStart = $(this).offset().top;
        var headerEnd = headerStart + $(this).height(); 
      
        if (currentPosition >= headerStart  && currentPosition < headerEnd) {
           
            $('a[href=#' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    list-style: none;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 140px
}
.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}

[id=intro] {
    height: 400px
}
[id=summary] {
    height: 960px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id=intro>Introduction</h2>
<p>Hello World</p>

<h2 id=summary>Summary</h2>
<p>Summary</p>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#intro">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#summary">Summary</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

A better approch to solve this would be to wrap them in section like on the page provided by the **OP** and pass `id` to those sections something like this:

```
<section  id=intro>
    <h2>Introduction</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</section>
<section  id=summary>
    <h2>Summary</h2>
    <p>Summary</p>
</section>
```

Now to have standard [HTML5 structural elements](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements) you need to wrap it in a [**main** element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

```
<main>

    <section  id=intro>
        <h2>Introduction</h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </section>
    <section  id=summary>
        <h2>Summary</h2>
        <p>Summary</p>
    </section> 

</main>
```

The set each section to a a full width `width: 100%` .

Good luck!

Comment: It isn't working for me, but I'll play with it some more over the weekend. Maybe there's a conflict with some of my existing JS or CSS. Thx!